# What is the sampling frequency of the accelerometers embedded in Android smartphone?

Tags: android, accelerometer, frequency, smartphone, sampling

I'm looking to know the **sample frequency of smartphone**, and - more important - if this parameter is equal for the most types of Android smartphone.

I know that  there are two mode of sampling: low at 20 Hz and standard at 100 Hz. But yesterday I've done some experiment with several type of smartphone and the "Samsung Galaxy Note 3" seems has a sample frequency of 200 Hz.

Now, my question is: is it true?
And, if yes, do you know where I could find one, or more, academic papers, or technical data sheets, about this issues?

Thank you in advance,
*Giacomo Alessandroni*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small googling found [Cochibos](http://accfreq.cochibo.com) work on the subject. It takes the data gathered with the [Accelerometer Frequency](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cochibo.accfreq&hl=en) app and reports it to the web page.

Looking for were the actual sample rate is defined it seems to be intrinsically connected with the device driver. I.e. the device driver sets the maximum sample rate as shown in [this paper](http://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/android-drivers/sensor-acceleration/adxl345). As the source code to the device drivers of commercial phones seldom are released it will be hard to find any reliable sources.

Comment: Thank you @mach, but I already know this application. I do not need know the sample frequency of my mobile device.

But I must find a data sheet or a paper to cite in my references.

Answer (score 0):

In this days I have found several applications for smartphones which analyze sample frequency of each mobile device.

The maximum sample frequency (this is the data that I'm looking for) isn't 100 Hz for all devices. There are some devices that uses more high sample frequency.

In my opinion, this fact depend by technological evolution, and by the fact that each manufacturer wants overtake the other.

So, do not exists a maximum sample frequency equal for all devices.